# Having problems with writing sql query on linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an SQL query which returns all accounts and in the top of the result table I have accounts which share same documents. Query below works just fine, but there is a problem implementing the same logic on linq.

```
select 
(
   select 
      COUNT(*) 
   from Signs X, Signs Y 
   where  X.AccountID = 2 and Y.AccountID = A.ID and X.DocID = Y.DocID
), 
*
from 
  Accounts A
where 
  A.ID != 2
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Can you write what problems you've got? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = from A in Accounts
             where A.ID != 2
             select new { Count = (from X in Signs
                                   from Y in Signs
                                   where X.AccountID == 2 &&
                                   Y.AccountID == A.ID &&
                                   X.DocID == Y.DocID
                                   select 1).Count(),
                          A };
```

Note: You could probably change the subquery to a [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) on `DocID` but i've left as is, so you can see the similarity between the SQL and the LINQ.

Example with a join:

```
var result = from A in Accounts
             where A.ID != 2
             select new { Count = (from X in Signs
                                   join Y in Signs on X.DocID equals Y.DocID
                                   where X.AccountID == 2 &&
                                   Y.AccountID == A.ID
                                   select 1).Count(),
                          A };
```

Comment: shouldn't X.DocID = Y.DocID be `X.DocID == Y.DocID` (emphasis on `==`) ?

Comment: That is exactly what i need! You've said it could be written using join. Can you show it. Actually i exactly tried joins, but i failed. Thank You!